# File for sublime text preferences that I can add to source code

Tags: sublimetext

Many people I work with use Sublime Text, but not all of us have it configured the same way. When we work on projects together, it's important for us to all have the same settings, e.g. soft tabs w/ 4 spaces. Short of instructing the user via the README, is there any way to automate this process via a preferences file that I can distribute as part of the source code?

For javascript projects, I can just drop a .jshintrc file that instructs jshint what my linting preferences are. Is there something similar for sublime text, a la .sublimertc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these settings can be defined in `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`, and on a per-project basis in the [`.sublime-project`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) file. For example, your project may have this in `MyProject.sublime-project`:

```json
{
    "settings": {
        "default_line_ending": "unix",
        "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
        "tab_size": 4,
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
        "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
    }
}
```

along with other settings to define directories, custom build systems and environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution might me to use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/). It works across editors/IDEs and is trivial to set up:

> EditorConfig helps developers define and maintain consistent coding styles between different editors and IDEs. The EditorConfig project consists of a file format for defining coding styles and a collection of text editor plugins that enable editors to read the file format and adhere to defined styles. EditorConfig files are easily readable and they work nicely with version control systems.

[editorconfig-sublime](https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime) is an EditorConfig plugin for Sublime Text.

A `.editorconfig` file is as simple as

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```